# async await , nodejs readfile and then do other

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I tried to read file through async/await and update the credentials , But i got response HI first and then hello in console.And Credentials also not updated in oauthClient2.

```
  const getFile = async (req, res, next) => {
    
      await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return null;
        console.log("hello")
        console.log(JSON.parse(token));
        oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      });
      
      console.log("HI")
        var service = google.drive({
          version: 'v3', 
          encoding: null
        });
        console.log(oauth2Client);
        await service.files.get({
          auth: oauth2Client,
          fileId: "1ZR8kkvb2JYVxcUjmlgfBJD2IYnisaiFn",
          alt: 'media'
        }, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
          }
          responder(res)(null,response);
        });
      
    }
```

Is there a way in which everything should run in a order?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are experiencing the error you see, is because the method you are running is asynchronous. You should instead use the alternative synchronous version:

```
let token;
try {
  token = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, 'utf8');
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
if(!token){ return; }

oauth2Client.credentials = token;
const service = google.drive({
  version: 'v3', 
  encoding: null
});

await service.files.get({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  fileId: "1ZR8kkvb2JYVxcUjmlgfBJD2IYnisaiFn",
  alt: 'media'
}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  responder(res)(null,response);
});
```

Ref: https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs